# Reading variables from multiple inline javascript block

Tags: javascript, scope

Is it possible to have multiple instances of the following script block, each with its unique variable values (but same variable names) and access them when external js that follows this block run?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
my_key = "1a";
my_time = new Date().getTime();
my_custom_params = {};
/*]]>*/
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='run.js?id=1901'></script>
```

Comment: FYI - `type="text/javascript"` can safely be removed from your code as that is the default type for `script` elements and `/*<![CDATA[*/` and `/*]]>*/` can be removed unless you will be passing the `script` tag to an XML parser (highly unlikely).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bus2z1oj/

Comment: Do you also have multiple external js files, each following on block?

Comment: @Bergi yes, each block has its following external js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated because all those variables are in the same global scope, but when each declaration script is directly followed by the script that uses the values, then it's possible indeed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
my_key = "1a";
my_time = new Date().getTime();
my_custom_params = {};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(key, time, params) {
    // scoped variables only available in here
    // won't be overwritten by the following script
}(my_key, my_time, my_custom_params));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// overwrites the variables
my_key = "2b";
my_time = new Date().getTime();
my_custom_params = {};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
{
    const locals = {
        key: my_key,
        time: my_time,
        params: my_custom_params
    };
    // locals.… available only in this scope
    // the object won't be overwritten or mutated by following scripts
}
</script>
…
```

You need to evaluate the global variables before they get overwritten the next time, and store their values in some safe place.

Of course, that's still a horrible practise. You really should make each script create a unique namespace (object) and put its values in there.

Comment: Yes, that'll work in all standard browsers. (OK, the `const` block scope thing only in the newer ones)

Answer (score 1):

No. `script` elements all exist in the same "scope" and that scope, by default is "Global", so if the same variable is declared/assigned a second time, it will overwrite the earlier value.

This is why we want to avoid the "global" scope and we do this by creating modules of code with functions.

As far as accessing the variables from an external script, that is possible, provided that the external script executes AFTER the variables have been declared and initialized and provided that the external script has access to the scope of the other variables.

Given that we want to avoid the global scope, you will have to make those variables available via a smaller scope, such as a function or object.

```html
<script>

  var my_key = "1a";
  var my_time = new Date().getTime();
  var my_custom_params = {};
  
  console.log(my_key);
  console.log(my_time);
  console.log(my_custom_params);

</script>

<script>
  // These assignments will overwrite the earlier values:
  my_key = "2b";
  my_time = new Date().getTime();
  my_custom_params = {other:"value"};
  
  console.log(my_key);
  console.log(my_time);
  console.log(my_custom_params);  

</script>
```

Here's an example of a way to avoid global scope but make the variables available to other code:

```html
<script>

  (function(){
    var my_key = "1a";
    var my_time = new Date().getTime();
    var my_custom_params = {};
  
    // Make a dummy object, give it new properties and assign the private values to them
    var dummy = {};
    dummy.my_key = my_key;
    dummy.my_time = my_time;
    dummy.my_custom_params = my_custom_params;
    
    // Expose the dummy object via a custom property on the global object
    window.myCustomNamespace = dummy;
  }());



</script>

<script>
  // As long as this code executes after the above code, it doesn't matter if this code
  // is in an external file or not.

  // We can now access the data via the custom namespace:
  console.log(window.myCustomNamespace.my_key);
  console.log(window.myCustomNamespace.my_time);
  console.log(window.myCustomNamespace.my_custom_params);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete Scott's answer, be aware that Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE) are just an option among others. What matters is the creation of an isolated scope to avoid conflicts in the global scope. Hence, thanks to ES6, you could also do this:

```html
<script>
{
  let my_key = "1a";
  let my_time = new Date().getTime();
  let my_custom_params = {foo: 'Foo'};
  
  console.log(my_key, my_time, my_custom_params);
}
</script>

<script>
{
  let my_key = "1b";
  let my_time = new Date().getTime();
  let my_custom_params = {bar: 'Bar'};
  
  console.log(my_key, my_time, my_custom_params);
}
</script>
```